# coding assembly using dcoder with error

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Just trying to code assembly with dcoder, but I've no idea why I gotten this error message:- 
Edited (17 sept 2017):-
I just found that dcoder are using NASM v2.10.09 for their assembly language.

```
source_file.asm:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
source_file.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
source_file.asm:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
source_file.asm:7: error: parser: instruction expected
source_file.asm:19: error: symbol `main' redefined
source_file.asm:19: error: parser: instruction expected
source_file.asm:20: error: parser: instruction expected
```

I learn to code using this style from my college & it run smoothly with my TASM which is the one that I use to run my assembly code. I'll be grateful if anyone can help me solve the prob thanks.

Source code:-

```
.model small

.data

    var1 db "Hello world$"

.code

main proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    lea dx, var1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

main endp

end main
```

Comment: When you say 'dcoder' do you mean [this](http://dcoder.tech/)?  I don't see 8086 assembler listed as one of their supported languages.

Comment: You seem to be writing 16-bit DOS code.  You know you that only works inside an emulator, or on a machine rebooted into DOS, right?  (Or maybe on 32-bit Windows).

Comment: @david wohlferd yes that's the one but dcoder shows that they supported assembly language that's why i feel weird. Because there's an option which can choose for the assembly.

Comment: "they supported assembly language" - The page I linked to above doesn't list assembler.  Do you have a better source?  If they *do* support assembler, then *whose* assembler?  GAS?  Masm?  x86?  ARM?  16bit assembler doesn't seem like it would be the most useful for them to support.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply @david wohlferd so 16bit assembler doesn't seem to work with 8086 assembly language

Comment: What I was trying to say was that while I don't know what dcoder supports (and I can't find any docs that describe it), I would be surprised to learn that they support 16 bit x86 assembler.  It's an uncommon platform these days.  If (as you say) they do support assembler, I also wouldn't expect them to use masm format, but rather GAS.  I can't give a better answer since I can't find any dcoder docs.

Comment: I just found that dcoder are using NASM v2.10.09 for their assembly language.

Comment: So post that as the answer.  NASM won't accept TASM directives like `.data`.  That's why it complains that you're trying to define a local label.